# Create Calendar Event in outlook with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, outlook, outlook-calendar

I need to create a calendar event in outlook using NodeJS script. I have searched every where and tried different npm packages but i didn't got the solution.

I have tried **Node-Outlook** NPM package but the documentation is not clear like how to create calendar event.

```
var outlook = require('node-outlook');

var newEvent = {
    "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
    }
};

let createEventParameters = {
    token: ['Access token'],
    event: newEvent,
    user : <user>
};
outlook.calendar.createEvents(createEventParameters, function (error, event) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);                 
    } else {
        console.log(event);                         
    }
});
```

This npm package return error :

```
REST request returned 401; body: {"error":{"code":"InvalidAudience","message":"The audience claim value is invalid 'aud'.
```

Please help me to solve this problem and also if you know any different way to create calendar event please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like your access token doesn't have proper claims as expected, drop that token on `jwt.io` and look for the `aud` field.

Comment: It Gives me "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000". What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

try to set this permission
Calendars.ReadWrite
in API permissions in Azure configuration